# IntellIJ not detecting java classes from the same Hybris module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud

IntellIJ does not detect some classes inside the packages of the same module :

[image]

[image]

If we do a quick search we find the class exactly in the package that IntellIJ doesnt find: (ctrl shift N):

[image]

And if we go to the PdfHelper class:

[image]

Can someone help me ? I don't know what is going on here , it just doesn't make sense. I've tried refreshing the project, ant clean all and indexing and still happens.

Answer (score 1):

You may check,
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources(tab)
Check your folder which is include PdfHelper is in right area(Source Folders)

And Build -> Build Artifact.

Check target path if PdfHelper.class exists or not.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I dont find sources tab neither Ant Build > Build Artifact , can you provide screenshot of the example?

Comment: Sorry I have no screenshot now because I have only security desktop which not allowed to have screenshot.
Try double "shift" button on your key board , and type "Build Artifact"

Comment: Not "Ant Build" , "Build"

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Language level to 9 (it was set to 8) solved the problems:

[image]

Comment: That's weird. What Hybris version are you using? I know that 1905 requires Java 11, and anything below that up to 6.0 requires Java 8.